# Sum of groups of four in a matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have the following matrix: first column are the values of 1 to 5, second column is 1 to 20, and the third column are random values.

```
1   1   2545
1   2   0
1   3   0
1   4   0
2   5   0
2   6   0
2   7   231
2   8   54587
3   9   41
3   10  1111
3   11  0
3   12  1213
4   13  0
4   14  0
4   15  0
4   16  0
5   17  898
5   18  6887
5   19  522
5   20  23
```

What I am trying to do is  to get the sum in groups of four when all values are different of zero. As an example, in the matrix the output I want is:

```
1   NaN
2   NaN
3   NaN
4   NaN
5   8330
```

Comment: How do you implement this matrix in MATLAB?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming that the first column delineates what values in the third column belong to what group, the easiest would be to change all values that are zero to `NaN`, then use [`accumarray`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html) to sum all of the values that belong to each group.  This is crucial because as soon as you sum over a matrix / array and **any** value is `NaN`, the result will be `NaN`.  This is nice because if you sum over each group, you will get a `NaN` result if at least one of the values in the group was equal to 0 before the change.

I'm going to assume that your matrix is stored in `X` like so:

```
X = [1   1   2545
1   2   0
1   3   0
1   4   0
2   5   0
2   6   0
2   7   231
2   8   54587
3   9   41
3   10  1111
3   11  0
3   12  1213
4   13  0
4   14  0
4   15  0
4   16  0
5   17  898
5   18  6887
5   19  522
5   20  23 ];
```

Make a copy of the third column, and let's do some magic:

```
col = X(:,3);
col(col == 0) = NaN;
out = accumarray(X(:,1), col);
```

We thus get:

```
out =

         NaN
         NaN
         NaN
         NaN
        8330
```

The nice thing about this approach is that the group ID for each value in your matrix doesn't have to be in order as you have placed in your post.

---

If however your matrix is guaranteed to have the order where each group consists of consecutive 4-tuples of elements, you can do the same thing with the `NaN` assignment, but you can avoid using `accumarray` and [`reshape`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html) the third column into a matrix of four rows then [`sum`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sum.html) over each row individually:

```
col = X(:,3);
col(col == 0) = NaN;
out = sum(reshape(col, 4, []), 1);
```